# Is it possible to manually choose which environment to deploy to in gitlab CI/CD?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-deployment

Does gitlab CI/CD have a web interface that allows us to choose which environment to deploy to for a single branch?

In jenkins, I can create such a web interface with [Parameterized Build Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build).

[image]

But I haven't found a way to do this with gitlab CI/CD.

Does anyone know how to do this?

------------------------------------ edit ------------------------------------

Here's [an issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/26281) that asks the same question. It looks like this feature hasn't been implemented yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure different jobs to achieve this. The general feature is described 
[here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments.html), but here's an example what your Gitlab-CI configuration could look like:

```
stages:
- deploy

deploy-env-a:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - deploy.sh
  environment:
    name: env-a.your-company.com

deploy-env-b:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - deploy.sh
  environment:
    name: env-b.your-company.com
```

In your CI pipeline the two jobs will appear in the deploy-stage and if you look at the output for the jobs, you should see something like "This job is deployed to env-a.your-company.com". The environment name is made available as an environment variable named "$CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME" so you can use it in your deploy script to copy resources to the proper target or whatever it is you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use manual job with environment variable to set the environment to deploy.
Since **GitLab 12.2**, you can specifying variables when running manual jobs:

> From [Gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines.html#specifying-variables-when-running-manual-jobs)
>
> > When running manual jobs you can supply additional job specific variables.
> >     You can do this from the job page of the manual job you want to run with additional variables.
> >     This is useful when you want to alter the execution of a job by using environment variables.

## Example:

```
stages:
- deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - <deploy script that use $DEPLOY_ENV to decide to which environment to deploy>
  when: manual
  environment:
    name: $DEPLOY_ENV
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Is it possible to use a drop-down menu to select the value? This can avoid typos.

Comment: I didn't find this option on GitLab's documentation, but I've found several closed issue requesting this feature, so maybe in future versions of GitLab

Answer (score 0):

You can use only/except (deprecated) or rules and associate environment them to git branch or variable.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesif

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except

```yaml
  only:
    - main  # execute only with main branch

  except:
    - main   # execute if branch is not main

  rules:   # execute [ manual | never |always ] only with main branch
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'main'
      when: manual # manual | never |always
```

.gitlab-ci.yml EXAMPLE:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

# define common deploy scripts that use CI Variables
.depl-scripts: &depl-scripts
      - cat $APP_DOTENV > app/.env.local
      - rsync --chown=$DEPLOY_OWNER:$DEPLOY_GROUP -e "ssh -p $DEPLOY_PORT"  ./ $DEPLOY_USER@$DEPLOY_SERVER:$DEPLOY_PATH/

deploy_prod:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: prod  # SET environment
  variables: # DEFINE PER ENV VARIABLES
    APP_ENV: ****
    DEPLOY_GROUP_PUBLIC: ****
    DEPLOY_GROUP_SRC: ****
    DEPLOY_OWNER: ****
    DEPLOY_PATH: /var/www/****
    DEPLOY_PORT: ****
    DEPLOY_SERVER: ****
    DEPLOY_USER: ****
  script:
    - *depl-scripts
  only:
    - main  # execute only with main branch


deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: staging  # SET environment
  variables: # DEFINE PER ENV VARIABLES
    APP_ENV: ****
    DEPLOY_GROUP_PUBLIC: ****
    DEPLOY_GROUP_SRC: ****
    DEPLOY_OWNER: ****
    DEPLOY_PATH: /var/www/****
    DEPLOY_PORT: ****
    DEPLOY_SERVER: staging.****
    DEPLOY_USER: ****
  script:
    - *depl-scripts
  only:
    - staging  # execute only with staging branch
```